# How to aggregate based on day, week in python flask postgresql

Tags: python, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I'm learning python flask trying to build small application. I'm encountering some problems querying postgresql data. I have gone through many links on how to perform aggregate function and tried few which doesn't seem working. It would be great if anyone help me find where I go wrong. Thanks. 
    My code:

```
    class DbUtils:
    db_string = "postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:xxx@localhost/postgres"

    def sum_day(self):
        db_string = "postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:xxx@localhost/postgres"
        db = create_engine( db_string )
        results = db.execute( "select current_date, sum(sample2.value),extract('day' from sample2.date_time) as dt from sample2 Group by dt" )
        return results

def sum_week(self):
        db_string = "postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:xxx@localhost/postgres"
        db = create_engine( db_string )
        results = db.execute( "select current_date, sum(sample2.value), extract('week' from sample2.date_time) as dt from sample2 Group by dt" )
        return results

@app.route( '/test/day', methods=['GET'] )
def sum_data():
    value = []
    dbUtils = DbUtils()
    result_Data = dbUtils.sum_day()
    for r in result_Data:
        str_value = str( r[1] ) + ' ' + 'mm'
        json_data = {"Sum_day": str_value, "dated": str(r[0])}
        return Response( json.dumps( json_data ), mimetype='application/json' )

@app.route( '/test/week', methods=['GET'] )
def sum_week():
    value = []
    dbUtils = DbUtils()
    result_Data = dbUtils.sum_week()
    for r in result_Data:
        str_value = str( r[1] ) + ' ' + 'mm'
        json_data = {"Sum_week": str_value, "dated": str(r[0])}
        return Response( json.dumps( json_data ), mimetype='application/json' )
```

Expected output:

```
{
"Sum_day":  11      #sum of values based on current_date 
"dated": 2019-10-04
}
```

But What I get is :

```
{
"Sum_day":  7       
"dated": 2019-10-04
}

{
"Sum_week": 21       
"dated": 2019-10-04
}
```

DB_sample2:

```
value       dated
1           2019-10-01 11:40:29.066806
2           2019-10-01 11:40:29.066806
3           2019-10-03 11:40:29.066806
4           2019-10-03 11:40:29.066806
5           2019-10-04 11:40:29.066806
6           2019-10-04 11:40:29.066806
```

I tried even with date_trunc funct but the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After changing the db fields from timestamp to date field. I executed following query which gives me exact result.
`select current_date,sum(sample.value) from sample Where date = current_date 
select extract('week'from sample.value) from sample`

Answer (score -1):

Change

---

select current_date, sum(sample2.value),extract('day' from sample2.date_time) as dt from sample2 Group by dt

---

to

---

```
select current_date
, extract('week' from sample2.date_time)
, extract('day' from sample2.date_time)
,  sum(sample2.value), as dt 
from sample2 
Group by current_date
, extract('week' from sample2.date_time)
, extract('day' from sample2.date_time)
```

---

added 2019 10 04

---

You need to count data on date field in data not current date:

---

```
select current_date;

--drop table products2;
CREATE TABLE products2 (
product_no integer,
name text,
price numeric CONSTRAINT positive_price CHECK (price > 0),
date_produced date
);

INSERT INTO products2 VALUES
(1, 'product 01', 105, '2019-10-01' );

INSERT INTO products2 VALUES
(1, 'product 02', 105, '2019-10-02' );

INSERT INTO products2 VALUES
(1, 'product 03', 105, '2019-10-02' );


select * from products2;

select date_produced
, extract('week' from date_produced)
, extract('day' from date_produced)
,  count(product_no)
from products2 
Group by date_produced
, extract('week' from date_produced)
, extract('day' from date_produced)
order by date_produced
, extract('week' from date_produced)
, extract('day' from date_produced)
;




date

1
04.10.2019 00:00:00



product_no
name
price
date_produced

1
1
product 01
105
01.10.2019 00:00:00

2
1
product 02
105
02.10.2019 00:00:00

3
1
product 03
105
02.10.2019 00:00:00



date_produced
date_part
date_part
count

1
01.10.2019 00:00:00
40
1
1

2
02.10.2019 00:00:00
40
2
2
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have already tried this. I still get the same value  i.e it sums values dated on 2019.10.03 and not based on current date. But query what I have written for sum_values based on week, so far works good. I have to check by next week data if its correct or not.

Comment: see my added code for a sql that counts on data datetime field not current date.

Comment: Hi, I think you didn't understand me correctly. I want to sum values based on current day and week, where I would like to have aggregation of values every day.

Comment: The sql posted shows a data field ‘date_time’ not the current date.  extract('day' from sample2.date_time). Shouldn’t that be extract('day' from sample2.currentdate)?

Comment: Actually your'e right, I too realized I gave time_stamp field. I changed my db datetime field to date field. Currently, my query is select current_date,sum(sample.value) from sample Where date = current_date.  This gives me sum of values with current_date. I hope this is the right query.